# Can this equality be possible in positive integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c,d >1$ be positive integers where $\gcd(a,b) =\gcd(c,d)=1$. Suppose that

$\dfrac{a^4}{b^4} = \dfrac{a(ac+bd)}{b^{2}d}$

Can this equality be actually possible for any such $a,b,c,d$ ?

My attempt: Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, observe that the LHS is in its simplest form. But notice that on the RHS, the highest power of $b$ in the denominator is $2$, which yields a contradiction since the corresponding such power on the *reduced* LHS is $4$ ?

Comment: Let $p=a/b$ and $q=c/d$ (and let them be in the lowest terms), then the equality is equivalent to $p^4=p(pq+1)$, or $p^3-pq-1=0$, or $q=p^2-1/p$. Does this help?

Comment: @user374734: You can simplify to $\frac{a^3}{b^2} = \frac{ac+bd}{d}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of integer solutions.

Simplifying the original equation yields
$$\frac{a^3}{b^2}=\frac{ac+bd}{d}.$$
Solving for $c$ gives
$$c = \frac{(a^3-b^3)d}{ab^2}.$$

Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, this forces $a \mid d$ and $b^2 \mid d$. Since $\gcd(c,d)=1$, no factor of $d$ can remain in the numerator. Hence one solution is $d=\pm ab^2$ and $c=\pm(a^3-b^3)$.

Now any integers $a$ and $b$ parameterize $c$ and $d$. For example, $a=1$ and $b=2$ yields $(c,d)=\pm(-7,4)$. Using the upper sign, we have $(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,-7,4)$, where plugging these into your original equation gives
$$\frac{a^4}{b^4} = \frac{1}{16} = \frac{a(ac+bd)d}{b^2d},$$
as expected.